# Item collection from server method

Tags: javascript, wakanda

Using the WakandaManager service in Quickstart gets a collection of items named 'tasks' that are listed on the client using the angular directive: `<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">`.

I have replaced the given code (below);

```
ds.Item.$all().$promise.then(function(event) {  
    $scope.tasks = event.result;  



ds.Item.getAll_items().$promise.then(function(event) {
    $scope.tasks = event.result;
    $scope.items = $wakanda.$transform.$objectToCollection(event.result);
});
```

The client html `{{tasks.length}}` gets the correct value, however; neither `<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">` or `<li ng-repeat="item in items">` displays the listed entities.

What is the correct syntax to display the entity collection returned by the server method?

Comment: If `getAll_items()` is a server method, what is the structure of it's return.

Comment: collection of entities: `var allItems = ds.Item.all();
 return allItems;`

Comment: It should work that way. Can you log `$scope.items` to see what `$objectToCollection` returns? Moreover, what is your Angular-Wakanda version?

Comment: Angular-Wakanda v11 build 11.197492

Comment: without $transform console gets: "Method result:  g.EntityCollection".  With $wakanda.$transform.objectToCollection(e.result) console gets "error - $wakanda not defined".

Comment: Note: wakanda service injection (var ds = WakandaManager.$wakanda.$ds;) does not produce an error when $wakanda.$transform.objectToCollection(e.result) is not in use.

Comment: Please provide you complete controller code.

Comment: .controller('TodoController', function($scope, WakandaManager) {
  WakandaManager.ready().then(function() {
    var ds = WakandaManager.$wakanda.$ds;


  ds.Item.getAll_items().then(function(event){
    ` //  $scope.tasks = event.result;`
   $scope.tasks = $wakanda.$transform.$objectToCollection(event.result);
    console.log("Method result: " , $scope.tasks);
    });
  });
});

Comment: Add it on your question by editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You directly use `$wakanda` variable but it's not defined at any place.

`$wakanda` is available through `WakandaManager`.

So, your call to `$transform` method should look like this:

```
ds.Item.getAll_items().$promise.then(function(event) {
    $scope.tasks = event.result;
    $scope.items = WakandaManager.$wakanda.$transform.$objectToCollection(event.result);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just now discovered that. I thought it was defined in WakandaManager. Thanks for looking at this and giving the answer.